# Working of Logical OR ( || ) in C?

Tags: c, logical-operators

I am a beginner C programmer and I was working with Logical Operators recently.

Is the logical or (`||`) zero whenever both operands are zero. Or is the working somewhat different?

How does it work ? Can someone please explain in detail!

Comment: The logical OR (||) is zero if_and_only_if both operands are zero. -> yep

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction

Comment: Rather an ironic name for this question

Comment: the C standard does not invent a new OR operation

Comment: Just as an aside WHY do you ask? did you run into a situation where that is NOT the case? if so, make sure that you don't have a typo in your program where you use a SINGLE `|` as in if ( a | b ) { do_something(); } ... because `|` is a valid operator, it's bitwise OR, and produces a different result than the logical OR `||`

Answer (score 14):

```
TRUE  || TRUE  == TRUE
TRUE  || FALSE == TRUE
FALSE || TRUE  == TRUE
FALSE || FALSE == FALSE
```

In C a zero value is FALSE and anything non-zero is TRUE

Also if the left-hand expression of the `||` evaluates to TRUE, the right-hand expression is not evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

The result of a logical OR (`||` operator in C) is true if EITHER of its inputs is true. Similarly logical AND (`&&` operator in C) is true if BOTH of its inputs are true.

```
A  B   A OR B   A AND B
0  0     0        0
0  1     1        0
1  0     1        0
1  1     1        1
```

(Note that 0 is FALSE and anything else is TRUE, 1 is conventionally used in truth tables like the above).

By combining these operators and the logical negation operator (`!` in C) you can create any operation you want, for example "exclusive OR" (which is true if exactly 1 of its inputs is true) can be written as `(A || B) && !(A && B)`.

Note that in C there is no guarantee that both sides of the operator will be evaluated if it's not necessary - for example if the left hand side of the `&&` operator evaluates to false, there is no point evaluating the right hand side.